# Android standart widget to display list of "clouds" with single selection

Tags: android, android-widget

From the "Developing Android app with Kotlin" Udacity course I remember that there was some standard widget to display a list of cloud-like items. And it was not the recycler view. But I can't remember its name and can't find the lesson about this widget by fastly browsing the course. Please, help me to recall the widget name.

The design is like following.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, guys, that was chips. Read more here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup